# HMGET: Empty result when passing params

Tags: go, redis, redigo

Using redigo, I'm trying to use HMGET. I'm passing a string slice as param in field. It is not working, returning empty result.

```
func HMGET(c redis.Conn, field []string)(){
        if err := c.Send("HMGET", HashName, field); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if err := c.Flush(); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        rval, err := c.Receive()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return rval, nil
}
```

This is working

```
c.Send("HMGET", r.HashName, "1", "2", "3")
```

Any suggestions why field when passed as param is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're sending is `HMGET r.HashName [1 2 3]`

Separate the arguments or add them the same slice and expand that slice as the variadic parameter. Since you're using type `[]string` you will need to convert that to an `[]interface{}` type as well:

```
func HMGET(c redis.Conn, field []string) {
    args := make([]interface{}, len(field)+1)
    args[0] = HashName
    for i, v := range field {
        args[i+1] = v
    }

    if err := c.Send("HMGET", args...); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    //////
```

Comment: the signature is `Send(cmd string, args ...interface{}) error`. so you need to convert to an interface{} slice first.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: oops, should have double-checked the docs ;)  will fix.

Comment: Now in result I'm getting  ["val1", "val2", "val3" ],   how do I get it in [ "val:pair" ]  format?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande: do you want the [StringMap](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#StringMap) function?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer so can I assume that the order of result is the same as that of input ?

Comment: @JimB I tried using StringMap function but is says need even no of arguments

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande: yes, that is for fetching the entire hash. If you just want specific fields, that you need to do it manually as Not_a_Golfer said.